# How do you make SoapUI assert against log output?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have a process that doesn't respond with output, it creates a log line in a file.  I want soapui to generate a request, then look in a log file for the expected output.

Comment: So where is this log file? How do you access it? What is it you are looking for in the log file? Perhaps you might want to start with [ask].

Comment: Why would it matter where the log file is, or how I access it?  As I said, I am looking for the expected output in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal, you can use a *Script assertion* in your *testStep* to check for the content in your log file after the request is executed.

So then you can use something like the follow simple *Groovy* code as *Script assertion*:

```java
// get your log content
def logFile = new File('pathTo/file.log')
// and assert if the log file 
// contains the expected string
assert logFile.getText('UTF-8').contains('expectedText')
```

NOTE: If you want to check that your server writes a log instead of creates a response then you've to execute your *SOAPUI* tests from the server machine itself or alternatively have a shared access to this log file from the machine where you will run the tests.

Hope it helps,